# How to set start and end row or interval rows for CSV in Nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to get particular part of excel file in Nifi. My Nifi template like that;

1. GetFileProcessor
2. ConvertExcelToCSVProcessor
3. PutDatabaseRecordProcessor

I should parse data between step 2 and 3.
Is there a solution for getting specific rows and columns ?
Note:If there is a option for cutting ConvertExcelToCSVProcessor, it will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Record` processors between `ConvertExcelToCSV` and `PutDatabaseRecord`.

to remove or override a column use `UpdateRecord`. this processor can receive your data via `CSVReader` and prepare an output for `PutDatabaseRecord` or `QueryRecord` . check View usage -> Additional Details...

in order to filter by column use `QueryRecord`.
here [an example](https://blogs.apache.org/nifi/entry/real-time-sql-on-event). this example receives data through `CSVReader` and makes some aggregations, you can as well do some filtering according to [doc](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html)

also [this post](https://blogs.apache.org/nifi/entry/record-oriented-data-with-nifi) had helped me to understand `Records` in `Nifi`